# Fixed subplots wiith matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a program that will show one plot on the right side of the window, and some text and options on the left side. I've created to subplots, one for the plot itself and one only containing text. My problem is that I want to be able to use the panning tool to pan in the plot, but it is also possible to "pan" in the other subplot, causing the text to move around in the window. Is there a way to "fix" one of the subplots, so that it is not possible to move with the panning tool?

Comment: It might be possible with multiple axes, but I think the more common way is to use a GUI framework like Tkinter, pygtk, wxpython or PyQt to draw the text and [embed a matplotlib figure](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, that works much better!